# link datasource and datadelegate of a UITableView to ViewController cause error 'Exc Bad Access'

Tags: iphone

I try to link datasource and datadelegate of a UITableView to ViewController.
It always causes error 'Exc Bad Access'.

I try to locate where causes this happen by setting the breakpoint in viewDidLoad of the ViewController and RootViewController and AppDelegate, unfortunetly, no result.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem might be. Though I know working with Tables can be a little tricky. I suggest this excellent tutorial that helped me get my head around some problems I had with making it work properly: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw&feature=player_embedded